# is it normal that audioRecord.js doesn't manage to record message longer than 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, encoding, mp3, ogg, recorder.js

I have been searching the web to find a fast, lightweight audio recording library. I finally found [audioRecord.js](https://github.com/sb2702/audioRecord.js). I would like to incorporate this library in my project in place of libmp3lame, which is very slow.

DEMO: http://sb2702.github.io/audioRecord.js/

I have been trying the /example/index.php but it fails to record messages longer than 30 seconds or so. Can you help me?

Comment: Are you getting the error with the stock example or with your own code?
What config values are you using? (type, bufferlen, recordasmp3, etc)

Comment: I successfully used the project's `example/index.php` to record for 60 seconds on my machine. What shows up in the example's log for you? Mine: `Recording... Stopped recording. Exporting to OGG`
What are your machine's specs? (esp: free memory)

Comment: First thank you for having edited my question Barett.

i'm using the /example/index.php. Above 30 secs it stops at "Exporing OGG".

Could it be server side ?

At first i started with a simple wav recorder but the uploads via ajax were not working above 3 seconds (took me a while to figure that). I understood i had some kind of limit near 700 ko weirdly (i can upload bigger via other means? we got godaddy linux shared). I need 77 secs records. I went for the libmp3lame, but it's long and the quality is bad. This one is fast and weightless. Thanks!

my project here http://thesyncbook.com/record

Comment: My machine is an Asus n750jv i7 with 8 gigs of memory, i dont think this is thé cause. Anyway i need this to work flawlessly on mobile phone. As of now my script with libmp3 lame is very slow on mobile, to slow to make it usable. Tonight I'll try to add the export ogg part to my script and we'll see. That way I can come back with a more precise question. Do you think that using the ogg encoding is the fastest and lightest and the most recognise on every browsers for that kind of USD (an audio comment system with 77 seconds messages). Thanks